Accumulate an array of coefficients based on an array of non unique items in Numpy
I have a numpy.array items of N~10^7 integers and a numpy.array coefficients of N floats.
items contains repeated entries, and only ~sqrt(N) unique entries.
I would like an array of unique entries unique_items and an array of accumulated coefficients unique_coefficients such that unique_coefficients[i] is the sum over j of coefficients[j] such that items[j]=unique_items[i].
For example if we have
items = [1,1,2,2,3,4]
coefficients = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

then
unique_items = [1,2,3,4]
unique_coefficients = [3,7,5,6]

The first entry of unique_coefficients is the sum of the 2 first entries of coefficients because the two first entries of items are 1 etc. Note that items is not necessarily sorted.
For now, I first compute a dict where each key is a unique element of items, and each value is a list of indices of the element in items, then I sum over the indices stored in this dict:
d = {}
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    if not item in d:
        d[item] = []
    d[item].append(index) 
unique_items = d.keys()
unique_coefficients = [np.sum(coefficients[i]) for i in d.values()]

Is there a way to avoid doing this python for loop and stay in numpy instead ? This for loop is where my code spends the most time.

you can obtain the unique items with np.unique and the other with np.bincount

You may want to use defaultdict instead of dict and make values it just sum of coefficients: d = collections.defaultdict(int), remove if, d[item] += coefficients[index]

Assuming the input items is sorted, get the unique values, then aggregate with add.reduceat:
items = np.array([1,1,2,2,3,4])
coefficients = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

unique_items, idx = np.unique(items, return_index=True)
# array([1, 2, 3, 4])
unique_coefficients = np.add.reduceat(coefficients, idx)
# array([3, 7, 5, 6])

If the input is not necessarily sorted, first add a sorting step with argsort:
items = np.array([1,2,2,3,4,1])
coefficients = np.array([1,3,4,5,6,2])

order = np.argsort(items)

unique_items, idx = np.unique(items[order], return_index=True)
# array([1, 2, 3, 4])
unique_coefficients = np.add.reduceat(coefficients[order], idx)
# array([3, 7, 5, 6])

You might also consider pandas's groupby.sum:
import pandas as pd

out = pd.Series(coefficients, index=items).groupby(level=0).sum()

1    3
2    7
3    5
4    6
dtype: int64

Finally, a simple pure python approach could be:
items = [1,1,2,2,3,4]
coefficients = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

out = {}
for i, c in zip(items, coefficients):
    out[i] = out.get(i, 0)+c

# {1: 3, 2: 7, 3: 5, 4: 6}

